mamopay inline credit card payments option in wordpress/woocommerce
I have a wordpress/woocommerce ecommerce store and integrate merchant payment plugin mamopay version 1.3.8 for payment collection.
The mamopay plugin option available popup credit card and I am looking for inline payment credit card option.
Any alternate option? or we need to fully customise
Someone recommend what is the solution for inline payment credit card enable on mamopay payment wordpress.
Example inline payment
enter image description here

The current mamopay plugin inline payment option is not available.
You need to customize plugin or apply custom code as reference below the official mamopay website https://help.mamopay.com/en/articles/9140223-inline-payments-integration
